# Как написать условие проверки ответов

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Я новичок.Пишу свою первую программу тест. Не могу понять, как написать условие проверки выбран ли правильный радиобаттон или нет. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    int index = myRadioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

    int id = v.getId();// id кнопки

    if (id == R.id.resalt) {

        if (index == -1) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Пожалуйста, выберите один из вариантов", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }// проверка нажал ли юзер вообще на radiobutton 

        if (index == 0) { как написать сравнение с переменной правильного ответа

        }

    }// вибран 1 radiobutton
```

Comment: В книгах Брайна Харди "Андроид. Программирование для профессионалов" и Пола Детела "Андроид для разработчиков" очень  подробно разбираются примеры разработки приложения-викторины (теста), уверен, эти книги очень вам помогут.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Объясню на примере.

Допустим, в `layuot` имеется:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_button_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/first_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/second_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/third_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Third"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

Далее:

```
private RadioGroup mRadioButtonGroup;
...
mRadioButtonGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_button_group);
...
int radioButtonID = mRadioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = mRadioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);

if (radioButton == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Пункт не выбран!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

switch (radioButton.getId()) {
    case R.id.first_radio_button:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Выбран первый пункт", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.second_radio_button:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Выбран второй пункт", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.third_radio_button:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Выбран третий пункт", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
}
```

---

В Вашем же примере, насколько я понимаю, номер выбранного пункта  – `index`, соответственно, Вы можете обработать это значение с помощью `switch – case`.